# instead of making device owner is there a way to make android app disable camera accross all users account

Tags: android, android-camera, device-admin, device-owner

We have android app as an Enterprise App which disables the camera of the Device. This functionality breaks when user switch to Guest user or similar functionality. Having app as Device Administer is not enough, We have found one solution to it i.e making app Device owner with nfc-Provisioning and similar approach but this requires the device to be in factory reset mode. So is there any other approach than this which will help us to disable camera across all profiles without factory resetting of the app. I believe this is not an idle approach as per users point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the guide for android Mobile as Administrator here you can disable the camera programmatic ally. You can refer to this link 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: we are already using this feature but it does not works in switch user case.

Comment: if user switch profile to guest user or similar functionality there he is able to access camera though it is already disabled in primary profile

Comment: Android Document Say that you can only do it with device administrator.You can also make a user as Administrator and disable some its feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can't and, while it restrains developers, it is actually a good thing for user's security.

Among other things, a Device Admin app **cannot**

- prevent the user from revoking the Device Admin rights,
- enforce policies across users,
- prevent the creation of new users.

It is relatively easy to lure Android users into giving Device Admin rights and many malwares have already tried to exploit this vulnerability through clickjacking or other means. So it is a good thing for users that Device Admin gives limited management capabilities and can be revoked.

In comparison Device Owner gives full management capabilities but requires factory reset which ensures there is a clear intent from the user.